# Referencing a element of a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Please consider the following code using a raw pointer, where I also reference different parts with another pointer;

```cpp
float* data = new float[9]; 
float* d = &data[3]; // may be d = &data[6]
```

Now, I am want to  use shared_ptr for above code, but I am unsure how to use shared_ptr for above case.

Comment: Presumably this is C++? please add a suitable tag. In general, are you also looking at e.g. vector instead of the array?

Comment: Actually, I want to  use array. Here, *data* will contains some coordinates of atoms, tand I want to manipulate different atom coordinate with *d*.

Comment: That's a case to handle with a `std::vector<float>`, not `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Please describe in words (in the question) what your goal functionality is. If you let 10 programmers draw their own conclusions from code, you could end up with 50 interpretations. (If it helps, think in terms of what you would search for to find this question. Because that's another good reason for relying on words before code.)

Comment: I think the main concern here is that you gave no context, no surrounding code or use case. i answered your question but as the comments indicate, many think that this is solving the problem you *think* you have, not the problem you actually have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a constructor that takes a shared pointer and an unrelated raw pointer. That's what you want. This can also point at whatever else you want, as long as it shares the lifetime of the passed-in shared pointer.

```cpp
// until C++17
std::shared_ptr<float[]> data(new float[9]);
// more efficient but requires C++20
auto data = std::make_shared<float[]>(9);

std::shared_ptr<float[]> d(data, &data[3]);

assert(&d[0] == &data[3]);
```

Comment: So they must have same life time? For example,  If  *data* is a  class attribute, and I access *data* in class function with a local pointer *d*, there will be double free?

Comment: @MasrulHudaParvez not a double free. What I mean is that the shared pointer cannot prove that the raw pointer `&data[3]` lives exactly as long as the array in `data`. You can make it point at anything. The new shared pointer simply increments the reference counter of `data`

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 and later, when `shared_ptr` is holding an array, it has an overloaded `operator[]` available, eg:

```
std::shared_ptr<float[]> data(new float[9]); 
// or, in C++20:
// auto data = std::make_shared<float[]>(9); 
float* d = &data[3];
```

Prior to C++17, simply `get()` the raw pointer from the `shared_ptr` and then use normal pointer arithmetic on it:

```
std::shared_ptr<float[]> data(new float[9]); 
float* d = data.get()+3;
```